# Wikipedia api counting appearances of a word.

Tags: php, api, wikipedia

i need to implement a measure of keyphraseness for a given word. Which means how important is that word, for example the word 'example' is less important than the word 'nuclear'. The proposed measure i m trying to implement is a simple one that takes into account the total number of appearances on wiki articles of that word and the times it appears in a link as

```
((link appearance)/(total appearances))
```

i can retrieve the number of total appearances for 'term' with

```
$url=http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?&action=query&list=search&srlimit=50&srredirects&srprop=snippet&srnamespace=0&srsearch=term;
$page=unserialize(file_get_contents($url));
$totalhits=$page["query"]["searchinfo"]["totalhits"];
```

what i need now is a way to retrieve the number that word appears in a link. Thnx in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you count as link appearance? Does e.g. `[[nuclear power]]` count?

Comment: @svick Yes that would count.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is not reasonably accessible though the API. Instead, you should download [dump of all articles](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dumps) (specifically, the `pages-articles` file) and go though that to get the information you need.